# android camera extract bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

i really need help with this i stuck.
i need to take a photo and use its bitmap in the program but i having issues , i tried this code i found but the result is a much much smaller picture for some reason

```
Bitmap resultpic=null;

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.getPath());
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, "new-photo-name.jpg");
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888);

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            Log.i("phototookwidth",Integer.toString(photo.getWidth()));
            Log.i("phototookheight",Integer.toString(photo.getHeight()));
            File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "myname.jpeg");
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            try {
                fos.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            resultpic=photo;
        }
    }
```

i have a code that displays the same bitmap but for some reason the size is like 10 times smaller than the photo taken on the same phone at the same moment which confuse me, please help

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    byte[] image_byte_array;
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            image = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            image_byte_array = stream.toByteArray();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("pathname");
            fos.write(image_byte_array);
            fos.close();
}}
```

something like this with error checking statements

Comment: i get error on the write with usuing try catch. and if possible i dont really need the file i just need the bitmap of the photo the size as it took picture of, regarding resizing i can work this out alone, also trying running it withought the writing and bitmap is null apperently